# TRIGGER CREATED successfully , but no triggers in information_schema TRIGGERS table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

hi i am trying to use triggers , my MySQL version is 5.5.8

the thing is when i create the trigger , PHPMyadmin says it is created successfully ,

**this is my trigger**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `check_pupil_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `pupil_data`
FOR EACH ROW  BEGIN
  IF  CHAR_LENGTH( NEW.DateOfBirth ) < 4 THEN
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT := 'check constraint on pupil_data.DateOfBirth  failed';
    END IF;
END$$  
DELIMITER ;
```

it says

```
Your SQL query has been executed successfully
DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER `check_pupil_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON  `pupil_data` 
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN 
IF CHAR_LENGTH( NEW.DateOfBirth ) <4
THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT :=  'check constraint on pupil_data.DateOfBirth  failed';

END IF ;
```

but when i

```
select * from information_schema.triggers

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0843 sec )
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.triggers
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

why is this happening , please help me , thanks in advance.

Comment: What does return SHOW CREATE TRIGGER query?

Comment: an error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Hmm, SHOW CREATE TRIGGER should show the trigger's information or return empty result-set. ...Try new_developer's solution.

Comment: @Devart thank you for the help. new_developers suggesion worked perfectly .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Check this.. It will help you ... and make sure query is same as is shown in image change ":=" to "="

Comment: wow that worked . and the validation also works  . brilliant answer , thank you so much , i worked more than 10 hours to solve this :D